# Magento 2.3 Remove product options wrapper if attribute set to yes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product

Could someone guide me how i can Remove product options wrapper if attribute set to yes

Screenshot
https://prnt.sc/uiebh1

I have successfully remove the add to cart button but when i trying to use same code into wrapper.phtml page showing error.

Code i m using

```
<?php if($_product->getData('remove_addtocart')==1): ?>
YES
<?php else: ?>
NO
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your code slightly as you are in a different block. you can achieve this by doing the following

```
<?php if($block->getProduct()->getData('remove_addtocart') === 1): ?>
 // If value is 1 then show
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Working fine